# Web Worker with imported modules in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-worker

I'm trying to make a web worker to prevent stalling the React main thread.  The worker is supposed to read an image and do various things.

The app was created using `create-react-app`.

Currently I have

`WebWorker.js`

```
export default class WebWorker {
    constructor(worker) {
        const code = worker.toString();
        const blob = new Blob(['('+code+')()'], {type: "text/javascript"});
        return new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob),  {type: 'module'});
    }
}
```

`readimage.worker.js`

```
import Jimp from "jimp";

export default () => {
    self.addEventListener('message', e => { // eslint-disable-line no-restricted-globals
        if (!e) return;
        console.log('Worker reading pixels for url', e.data);
        let data = {};

        Jimp.read(e.data).then(image => {
            // jimp does stuff
            console.log('Worker Finished processing image');
        })

        postMessage(data);
    })
};
```

And then in my React component `AppContent.js` I have 
    import WebWorker from "./workers/WebWorker";
    import readImageWorker from './workers/readimage.worker.js';

```
export default function AppContent() {
    const readWorker = new ReadImageWorker(readImageWorker);
    readWorker.addEventListener('message', event => {
        console.log('returned data', event.data);
        setState(data);
    });

    // callback that is executed onClick from a button component
    const readImageContents = (url) => {
        readWorker.postMessage(url);
        console.log('finished reading pixels');
    };
}
```

But when I run it, I get the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jimp__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default is not defined

How can I properly import a module into a web worker?

## EDIT:

As per suggestions from Kaiido, I have tried installing `worker-loader`, and edited my webpack.config.js to the following:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.worker\.js$/,
                use: { loader: 'worker-loader' }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

But when I run it, I still get the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jimp__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not defined

Comment: Hi @cclloyd did you ever get at the bottom of it?

Comment: @mikey not necessarily, but you can peek at working code if you want https://gitlab.com/cclloyd1/oledonline/-/tree/master/src

Comment: thanx, for me turned out the problem wasn't really the same as yours. But again, thank so much for sharing this

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too much into React, so I can't tell if the module-Worker is the best way to go (maybe [worker-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader) would be a better solution), but regarding the last error you got, it's because you didn't set the `type` of your Blob when you built it.

In this case, it does matter, because it will determine the Content-Type the browser sets when serving it to the APIs that fetch it.
Here Firefox is a bit more lenient and somehow allows it, but Chrome is picky and requires you set this `type` option to one of the many javascript MIME-types.

```js
const script_content = `postMessage('running');`;

// this one will fail in Chrome
const blob1 = new Blob([script_content]); // no type option
const worker1 = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob1), { type: 'module'});
worker1.onerror = (evt) => console.log( 'worker-1 failed' );
worker1.onmessage = (evt) => console.log( 'worker-1', evt.data );
// this one works in Chrome
const blob2 = new Blob([script_content], { type: "text/javascript" });
const worker2 = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob2), { type: 'module'});
worker2.onerror = (evt) => console.log( 'worker-2 failed' );
worker2.onmessage = (evt) => console.log( 'worker-2', evt.data );
```

But now that this error is fixed, you'll face an other error, because the format `import lib from "libraryname"` is still not supported in browsers, so you'd have to change `"libraryname"` to the path to your actual script file, keeping in mind that it will be relative to your Worker's base URI, i.e probably your main-page's origin.

Comment: The second one removes 1 of the identical errors I posted.  But I still get that error. (chrome)

Comment: @cclloyd I'm not sure to understand your comment. Could you be more clear as to what error you get?

Comment: Sorry, different error.  The one I get if I don't have any type in the constructor.  `Uncaught ReferenceError: jimp__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default is not defined`, source references the line where I call Jimp in the worker function.

Comment: As I said, I can only answer the native Worker error. One thing is your path `import Jimp from "jimp"` format is still not supported in browsers, you'd have to use an absolute URL here (`import Jimp from "https://yoursite/assets/jimp.js"`). But since you are using webpack, why not use that [worker-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader) module?

Comment: I tried adding worker-loader but still get the error.  Edited my post to reflect changes.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem. Firefox could not show me where exactly the error was (in fact it was plain misleading...) but Chrome did.
I fixed my problem by not relying on an import statement (importing one of my other files) which would only have worked within a React context. When you load a Worker script (via the blob()
/ URL() hack), it has no React context (as it is loaded at runtime and not at transpile time). So all the React paraphernalia __WEBPACK__blah_blah is not going to exist / be visible.
So... within react... import statements in worker files will not work.
I haven't thought of a workaround yet.