# can i import a library from node modules in web worker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-worker

i am working on a small app in which I am passing some data from main class to the web worker to train model using RandomForestClassifer method from 'ml-random-forest' module.
I tried to import the above method into the web worker but i get the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: ml_random_forest__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not defined at onmessage`

*worker.js*

```
import { RandomForestClassifier as RFClassifier } from 'ml-random-forest';

export default ()=>{

onmessage=(e)=>{
    console.log('in worker')
    const classifier = new RFClassifier(e.data[0]);
    console.log('classifer'+ classifier)
    classifier.train(e.data[1],e.data[2])

    var result = classifier.predict(e.data[3]);
    var accuracy = calculateAccuracy(result, e.data[4]);
    console.log(accuracy)
    postMessage(accuracy)
}

const calculateAccuracy = (result, test_labels) => {
    let hits = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i<result.length; i++){
        if(result[i] == test_labels[i]){
            hits++;
        }
    }
    let rcl =  hits / result.length;
    return rcl;
}
}
```

*main.js*

```
const myworker = new webWorker(worker);
//some extra code inbetween

 setTimeout(async () => {  
        // training_labels = transformLabelsIntoEnums(training_labels);
        // test_labels = transformLabelsIntoEnums(test_labels);

        const options = {
            seed: 132456,
            maxFeatures: props.state.rf_config.rf_maxFeatures,
            replacement: false,
            nEstimators: props.state.rf_config.rf_nEstimators
          };

        const classifier = new RFClassifier(options);
        // await sleep(1000000);
         console.log('classifier '+classifier)
          myworker.onmessage = function (event){
              accuracy=event.data;
              console.log(event.data);
        }

       
        console.log('calling worker')
        
    myworker.postMessage([options,training_dataset,training_labels,test_dataset,test_labels]);
  }, 100);
```

Comment: I think the problem is more with the webpack config? Is the worker.js an entrypoint?

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61093264/web-worker-with-imported-modules-in-react?rq=1 ?

Comment: What JavaScript file are you loading into the webWorker, have you created this JS file as an entry point inside webpack?

Comment: i am trying to load ml-random-forest `https://www.npmjs.com/package/ml-random-forest` in worker. 
do I have to create the worker.js as entry point?